# Differential of second order

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Consider $f:\mathbb R^n→\mathbb R^m$  and $g:\mathbb R^m→\mathbb R^k$ . Then $(g∘f):\mathbb R^n→\mathbb R^k$ and, if both of them are differentiable,

$ D(g∘f)p=Dg(f(p))∘Df(p)=(Dg)(f(p))*(Df)(p).$

How I can prove that

$(D^2(g∘f))p=(D^2g)f(p)*((Df)(p))^2+(Dg)f(p)*(D2f)p$.

Thanks

Comment: Notice that the second derivative is not a matrix but a tensor / bilinear map. You should explicitly state the arguments, as your formula has some dimension issues.

Comment: Ok but I would like to work with the chain rule. I try to prove it like this:

Comment: you need the chain rule. I never claimed the opposite.

Comment: Yes, ok but I like to use the chain rule there but I don´t know how. When I try to prove it I only prove that $(D^2(g∘f))p= D(D(g∘f)p)=D(Dg(f(p))∘Df(p))=D((Dg)(f(p))*(Df)(p))$ But I don´t know what now.

Comment: $(D^2(g∘f))p= d^2zj/dxhdxi$=SUM q=1 to k of SUM w=1 to k of $d^2zj/dywdyq*dyp/dxh*dyq/dxi$ + sum q=1 to k of $dzj/dyq*d^2yq/dxhdxi $ but what is the next step ?

Comment: you should update your question. Your comment is hard to read

Comment: Let g∘f=(z1,...,zn). Then
$(D^2(g∘f))p=d^2zj/(dxh*dxi)$ =SUM q=1 to k of SUM w=1 to k of [$d^2zj/(dywdyq)∗dyp/(dxh)∗dyq/(dxi)d^2zj/(dyw*dyq)∗dyp/(dxh)∗dyq/(dxi)$] + sum q=1 to k of[ $dzj/(dyq)∗d^2yq/(dxh*dxi)$] from the chain rule. I am sorry but I do not how to use symbol SUM ....

Comment: Type `\sum_{i=1}^n` for $\sum_{i=1}^n$, `x_i` for $x_i$, or `\frac{df}{dy}` for $\frac{df}{dy}$. Again, it is best to update and expand your question with thing you tried.

Comment: $z:=g∘f=(z1,...,zn)$  then we have
$(D^2(g∘f))p=\frac{d^2zj}{dxh*dxi}  =(\sum\sum{\frac{d^2z}{dya*dyb}}*\frac{dyb}{dxh}*\frac{dyh}{dxi} )+  (\sum{\frac{dzj}{dya}}*\frac{d^ya}{dxh*dxi})$ so i did this but I really do not know what is the next step....

Comment: so I used the chain rules and I got this. Now, I do not know how to "get" the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $L(X,Y)$ denote the space of linear maps between finite dimensional normed space $X$ and $Y$.

Let $B(p) = Dg(f(p))\in L(\mathbb R^m, \mathbb R^k)$. That is, $B(p)$ is a linear map from $\mathbb R^m$ into $\mathbb R^k$, or a $k\times m$ matrix. Let $A(p) = Df(p) \in L(\mathbb R^n, \mathbb R^m)$.
So we have $D(g\circ f)(p) = B(p)\circ A(p) \in L(\mathbb R^n, \mathbb R^k)$.
Now consider
$$ D^2(g\circ f)(p) = D(B(p) \circ A(p)), $$
which is a linear map from $\mathbb R^n$ into $L(\mathbb R^n, \mathbb R^k)$.

Notice that composition of linear maps (the same as multiplication of matrices) is a bilinear map.
Thus, we have
$$ D(B(p)\circ A(p))[h] = DB(p)[h]\circ A(p) + B(p) \circ (DA(p)[h]) $$
with
$$ DB(p)[h] = D^2 g(f(p))[Df(p)[h]] $$
and
$$ DA(p)[h] = D^2 f(p)[h]. $$
In particular, we have
$$ D^2(g\circ f)(p)[h] = (D^2 g(f(p))[Df(p)[h]]) \circ Df(p) + Dg(f(p))\circ(D^2 f(p)[h]). $$
Now, one can show that higher derivatives (in sense of totally differentiable) are symmetric. Thus, people usually identify the second derivative with a symmetric bilinear map. Thus, we can also write
$$ D^2(g\circ f)(p)[h, \tilde h] = D^2 g(f(p)[Df(p)[h], Df(p)[\tilde h]] + Dg(f(p))[D^2 f(p)[h, \tilde h]]. $$